# Passing value to nested attribute Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

So I have an object

```
margins = {
            'xs': {
                'marginTop': '-',
                'marginRight': '-',
                'marginBottom': '-',
                'marginLeft': '-'
            }
            'md': {
                'marginTop': '-',
                'marginRight': '-',
                'marginBottom': '-',
                'marginLeft': '-'
            }
            'lg': {
                'marginTop': '-',
                'marginRight': '-',
                'marginBottom': '-',
                'marginLeft': '-'
            }
            'xl': {
                'marginTop': '-',
                'marginRight': '-',
                'marginBottom': '-',
                'marginLeft': '-'
            }
            'hd': {
                'marginTop': '-',
                'marginRight': '-',
                'marginBottom': '-',
                'marginLeft': '-'
            }
        }
```

and a function that passing 4 values

```
const {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
            attributes: { margins, paddings },
            setAttributes,
        } = props;
    
const updateProps = ( breakName, type, name, size ) => {
    
                if ( breakName && type === 'margin' && name && size ) {
                    const newMargins = { ...margins };
                    newMargins[ breakName ][ name ] = size;
                    setAttributes( { margins: newMargins } );
                } else if ( breakName && type === 'padding' && name && size ) {
                    const newPaddings = { ...paddings };
                    newPaddings[ breakName ][ name ] = size;
                    setAttributes( { paddings: newPaddings } );
                }
            };
```

For some reasons when I pass updateProps(xl, margin, marginTop, 16) all breakpoints (xs, md, lg, xl, hd) get the same value from size.

I have looked into this solution post for solution https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/5191 but is not working for me.